# Group Visualization objects of Kibana in Dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Kibana. I have a requirement to group, similar topic visual objects, in Dashboard. For Example: Suppose I have Pie Object for CARS,Bike and  Monitors, then I need to group the CARS,BIKES Pie under Automobiles Heading and Monitors under Computers Heading in Dashboard. Could you please help?

Comment: Have you been through the documentation and training on ElasticSearch and Kibana? This question really should be able to answered in the documentation.

Comment: Currently, am using Mark Down visualisation tool to create the view as per my requirement